# Parse CSV to find names corresponding to code, then copying folders with matching code to folders with corresponding name

Tags: bash, shell, unix, scripting

I'm trying to automate the packaging of files and contents from various sources using a bash script.

I have a main directory which contains `pdf` files, a csv file, and various folders with additional contents. The folders are named with the location code they pertain to, e.g. `190`, `191`, etc.

A typical row in my csv file looks like this: `form_letters_Part1.pdf,PX_A31_smith.adam.pdf,190,`

Where the first column is the original `pdf` name, the second is what it will be renamed to, and the third column is the location code the person belongs to.

The first part of my script renames the `pdf` files from the cover letters format to the `PX_A31...` format, and then creates a directory for each file and moves them into it.

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh bash
sed 's/"//g' rename_list_lab.csv | while IFS=, read orig new num; do 
    mv "$orig" "$new"
done
echo 'Rename  Done.'
for file in *.pdf; do
    mkdir "${file%.*}"
    mv "$file" "${file%.*}"
done
echo 'Directory creation done.'
```

What needs to happen next is the folders with the location-specific contents get copied into those new directories just created, corresponding to the location code from the csv file.

So I tried this after the above `echo 'Directory Creation Done.'` line:

```
echo 'Directory Creation Done.'
sed 's/"//g' rename_list.csv | while IFS=, read orig new num; do 
    for folder in *; do
        if [[ -d .* = "$num" ]]; then
            cp -R "$folder" "${file%.*}"
        fi
done
echo 'Code Folder Contents Sort Done.'
```

However this results in a syntax error:

```
syntax error in conditional expression
syntax error near `='
`                    if [[ -d .* = "$num" ]]; then'
```

EDIT: To clarify the second part `if` statement, the intended logic of the statement is as follows: For the items in the current directory, if it is a directory, and the name of the directory matches the location code from the csv, that directory should be copied to any directories which have that same corresponding location code in the csv.

In other words, if the newly created directory from the first part is `PX_A31_smith.adam` whose location code in the csv line above is 190, then the folder called `190` should be copied into the directory `PX_A31_smith.adam`.

If three other people also have the 190 code in the csv, the `190` directory should also be copied to those as well.

EDIT 2: I resolved the syntax error, and also realized I had an nonterminated `do` statement. Fixing those, still seem to be having trouble with the evaluation of the `if` statement. Updated script below:

```
#!/usr/bin/tcsh bash
sed 's/"//g' rename_list.csv | while IFS=, read orig new num; do 
    mv "$orig" "$new"
done
echo '1 Done.'
for file in *.pdf; do
    mkdir "${file%.*}"
    mv "$file" "${file%.*}"
done
echo '2 done.'
sed 's/"//g' rename_list.csv | while IFS=, read orig new num; do 
    for folder in * ; do
        if [[ .* = "$num" ]]; then
            cp -R "$folder" "${file%.*}"
            else echo "No matches found."
        fi
    done
done
echo '3 Done.'
```

Comment: Could you tell us what that if statement is supposed to represent?   `-d` checks whether the next argument is a directory. So right now, you are checking whether `.*` is a directory, and the `= "$num"` is extra.  That is at the least why you are getting a syntax error.  Also in the first part of the script, you are check `if [[ -f *.pdf ]]; then` which translates to <if there is a .pdf file in this directory>`; then`

Comment: Just added an edit with my intention behind the `if` statement. Also thanks for pointing out the issue with the first part, I accidentally copied that from an old attempt at what I wanted. I updated it with the correct form of the first script section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not really sure if this answers your question, but I think it will at least set you on the right track.  Structurally, I just combined all of the loops into one.  This removes some of the possible logic errors that would not be considered syntax errors like the use of `$file` in the second part.  This is a local variable to the loop in the first part and no longer exists.  However, this would be interpreted as an empty string.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
#^Fixed shebang line.

sed 's/"//g' rename_list.csv | while IFS=, read -r orig new num; do 

    if [[ -f $orig ]]; then          #If the file we want to rename is indeed a file.
        mkdir "${new%.*}"            #make the directory from the file name you want
        mv "$orig" "${new%.*}/$new"  #Rename when we move the file into the new directory

        if [[ -d $num ]]; then       #If the number directory exists
            cp -R "$num" "${new%.*}" #Fixed this based on your edit.
        else
            #Here you can handle what to do if the number directory does not exist.
            echo "$num is not a directory."
        fi

    else  
        #Here you can handle what to do if the file does not exist.
        echo "The file $orig does not exist."
    fi

done
```

Edited based on your clarification

Note:  This is pretty lacking as far as error checking goes.  Remember, any of these functions could fail, which will have unwanted behavior.  Either check `if [[ $? != 0 ]]` to check the exit status (0 being success) of the last issued command.  You could also do something like `mkdir somedir || exit 2` to exit on failure.